# How do I differentiate this stochastic process?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I have the following stochastic equation:

$X(t)=e^{-t}W(e^{2t})$

How do I now find $dX$? I have tried using Ito's equations but I seem to get lost in the calculus ($W$ is a Brownian motion).

Comment: Is $W$ is Lambert W?

Comment: W is a Brownian motion

Comment: This question is in the Close Queue because you have not given sufficient details. Please includ some context, such as background and motivation, relevant definitions, possible strategies, your current progress, etc. Otherwise, you will no doub tfind this question closed quite soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically copy-paste from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma

Set $$h(t,x)=e^{-t}x$$
so $$X(t)=h\left(t,W(e^{2t})\right)$$ and consider $${\rm d}X(t)= \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}\left(t,W(e^{2t})\right){\rm d}t + \frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\left(t,W(e^{2t})\right) {\rm d}(W(e^{2t})) + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 h}{\partial x^2} \left(t,W(e^{2t})\right) \left({\rm d}(W(e^{2t}))\right)^2 \\
=-e^{-t}W(e^{2t}) \, {\rm d}t + e^{-t} {\rm d}(W(e^{2t})) + 0 \\
=-e^{-t} W(e^{2t}) \, {\rm d}t + \sqrt{2} \, {\rm d}W(e^{2t})$$
where ${\rm d}W$ has variance ${\rm d}t$.

---

I think in the last line, second term it should be $\sqrt{2}$ instead of $2e^{t}$, as $${\rm d}(W(e^{2t}))=W(e^{2(t+{\rm d}t)})-W(e^{2t}) = W(e^{2t}+2e^{2t}{\rm d}t)-W(e^{2t}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,2e^{2t}{\rm d}t)$$ for infinitesimal ${\rm d}t$, while $${\rm d}W(e^{2t}) \sim \mathcal{N}(0,{\rm d}t)$$
i.e. $$({\rm d}(W(e^{2t})))^2=2e^{2t}({\rm d}W(e^{2t}))^2 \, .$$

---

Could you add some further information on how you obtained this motion and what you would expect and why?